# How to get keyword ranked and traffic from a specific region?

Tags: keywords, local-seo, ranking

I am working on a site that has good traffic and ranking form many countries. Our website is  basically about Japanese used cars exporters and now we want to become more famous in Africa regions such as:

- Congo
- Zambia
- Uganda

But our keyword ranking and traffic is very low in these countries than those in other countries.

What can we do to improve our rankings that will improve our traffic from these regions in Africa?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much you can do about it besides localization, traditional marketing, online advertising and social midia.

Make sure you have your content available on the languages you are targeting. 
Most of the online advertising tools let you narrow your ads on a per country basis.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to fundamentals: I'd suggest looking at whether people in those locations are actually looking for what you offer. If not, is it because they don't want it, or do they just not *know* they want it yet?

If the market does exist, it's likely that terminology is different. Chances are you need to create content specifically for those markets, addressing the local search terms.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is to create subdomains with the content targeted on countries you need.
E.g. for Congo you may create **cg.yoursitedomain.com** and place the information about your business activity and services you are currently supported for Congo. You should do it on their national language or language which is the most popular in this country. Also use in text keywords with local targeting (e.g. Japanese used cars exporters in Congo etc.)